# Magento - PHP Error Allowed memory size after change URL Key of category product

Tags: php, magento, out-of-memory, categories

I'm working on Magento Community 1.8.1.0, and after I've created thousands of products, I've seen the URL Key of a main category is uncorrect. So, I've decided to change it.

After change, when I see the main category I get the error:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 2 bytes)
in /home/web/www.marangonigioielli.com/www/shop/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 290
```

I'm trying to get some additional debug information, but I cannot modify PHP configuration, for get maybe a debug trace of what happens.

I've read on many pages on the Web, increasing the memory limit of PHP is not always the solution, it can be a problem of code.

"You are my last hope!"

Comment: Try to make reindex from Index Management of all and clear cache memory from Cache Management

Comment: Thanks for your supply. I've enabled the Debug Mode in order to get some PHP error and I got with surprise there was a plugin with some little error in the code. After resolved these issues, the Magento come back to work correctly. Unfortunately I've lost all editings I've made. Sorry for the inconvenience.